# Can not login to website using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

I am trying to programmatically log on 1 site. I have following code that does not work:

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.smarsy.ua");
while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser.Document;
doc.GetElementById("username").InnerText = "username";
doc.GetElementById("password").InnerText = "password";
doc.GetElementById("inputButton").InvokeMember("Click");

while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

webBrowser.Navigate("http://smarsy.ua/private/parent.php");
while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
```

webpage:

```
...
<input class="validate[required,minSize[8],custom[onlyNumber]] full" type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="8" value="" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes" data-cip-id="username" autocomplete="off">
...
<input class="validate[required,minSize[6],custom[onlyPassword]] full" type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="24" value="" data-cip-id="password" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes">
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ввійти" class="full passive">
```

What's wrong? Or you might suggest me a good framework to scrap the sites with C#

Comment: Have you verified the Id's of textBoxes for username , password and also the button? If yes then re-verify your InvokeMember by trying to click any other button/link on the page

Comment: I've added HTML source code to the question. There is no other buttons on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the button does not get clicked with your method. I tested it as following:

Replace your line of code:

```
doc.GetElementById("inputButton").InvokeMember("Click");
```

With this one:

```
HtmlElementCollection Bclick = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement Btn in Bclick)
        {
            string name = Btn.Name;
            if (name == "submit")
                Btn.InvokeMember("click");
        }
```